# 6502 nes game's stack overflows when jumping to a subroutine

Tags: assembly, stack-overflow, 6502, nes

When I run this chrome dinosaur clone for the nes I wrote in 6502 assembly, it causes a stack overflow for some reason.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
1. isJumping  = %00000001
2. isFalling  = %00000010
3. isGameOver = %00000001 
4. 
5. collisionram = $700
6. 
7. 
8. .segment "HEADER"
9. 
10. .byte "NES"
11. .byte $1A
12. .byte $02
13. .byte $01
14. .byte %00000000
15. .byte $00
16. .byte $00
17. .byte $00
18. .byte $00
19. .byte $00, $00, $00, $00, $00
20. 
21. .segment "BSS"
22. 
23. 
24. .segment "ZEROPAGE"
25. gameState:              .res 1
26. playerXPos:             .res 1
27. playerYPos:             .res 1
28. cactus1XPos:            .res 1
29. cactus1YPos:            .res 1
30. cactus2XPos:            .res 1
31. cactus2YPos:            .res 1
32. cactusTmpX:             .res 1
33. cactusTmpY:             .res 1
34. playerState:            .res 1
35. playerJumpSpeed:        .res 1
36. playerFallSpeed:        .res 1
37. cactusMoveSpeed:        .res 1
38. collisionHandler:       .res 1
39. walkingAnimationState:  .res 1
40. walkingAnimationDelay:  .res 1
41. playerXCollisionIndex:  .res 1   
42. playerYCollisionIndex:  .res 1
43. cactusXCollisionIndex:  .res 1
44. cactusYCollisionIndex:  .res 1
45. 
46. .segment "STARTUP"
47. 
48. 
49. .segment "CODE"
50. 
51. 
52. Reset:
53.     sei 
54.     cld         
55.     ldx #$40
56.     stx $4017
57.     ldx #$FF
58.     txs 
59.     inx
60.     stx $2000
61.     stx $2001 
62.     stx $4010
63. :
64.     bit $2002
65.     bpl :-
66.     txa 
67. 
68. clearmem:
69.     sta $0000, x
70.     sta $0100, x
71.     sta $0300, x
72.     sta $0400, x
73.     sta $0500, x
74.     sta $0600, x
75.     sta $0700, x
76.     lda #$FE
77.     sta $0200, x
78.     lda #$00
79.     inx 
80.     bne clearmem 
81. :
82.     bit $2002
83.     bpl :-
84.     lda #$02
85.     sta $4014
86.     nop 
87.     lda #$3F
88.     sta $2006
89.     lda #$00
90.     sta $2006
91.     ldx #$00
92. 
93. loadpalettes:
94.     lda PaletteData, x
95.     sta $2007
96.     inx 
97.     cpx #$20
98.     bne loadpalettes
99. 
100. init:
101.     ldx #$00
102. initCollisionRam:
103.     lda CollisionMap, x
104.     sta collisionram, x
105.     inx
106.     cpx #$78
107.     bne initCollisionRam
108.     lda #$04
109.     sta cactusMoveSpeed
110.     lda #$03
111.     sta playerXPos
112.     lda #$A2
113.     sta playerYPos
114.     lda #$A2 
115.     sta cactus1XPos
116.     lda #$F1
117.     sta cactus2XPos
118.     lda #$AA
119.     sta cactus1YPos
120.     lda #$9F
121.     sta cactus2YPos 
122. 
123. enableNMI:
124.     cli 
125.     lda #%10010000
126.     sta $2000
127.     lda #%00011110
128.     sta $2001
129. 
130. Forever:
131.     jmp Forever
132. 
133. CheckBackgroundCollision:
134.     txa 
135.     lsr 
136.     lsr 
137.     lsr 
138.     lsr 
139.     lsr 
140.     lsr 
141.     sta collisionHandler
142.     tya 
143.     lsr 
144.     lsr  
145.     lsr
146.     asl 
147.     asl 
148.     clc 
149.     adc collisionHandler
150.     tay 
151.     txa 
152.     lsr 
153.     lsr 
154.     lsr 
155.     and #%00000111
156.     tax 
157.     lda collisionram, y
158.     and BitMask, x
159.     rts 
160. 
161. checkCactusCollision:
162. 
163.     ldx #$00
164.     stx playerXCollisionIndex
165.     stx playerYCollisionIndex
166.     stx cactusXCollisionIndex
167.     stx cactusYCollisionIndex
168.     ldy #$00
169. checkCollisionY:
170.     ldx #$00
171.     stx playerXCollisionIndex
172. checkCollisionX:
173.     
174.     lda playerXPos
175.     clc 
176.     adc playerXCollisionIndex
177.     pha
178.     lda cactusTmpX
179.     sta cactusXCollisionIndex
180.     pla
181.     cmp cactusXCollisionIndex
182.     bne :+
183.     lda playerYPos 
184.     clc 
185.     adc playerYCollisionIndex
186.     pha 
187.     lda cactusTmpY
188.     sta cactusYCollisionIndex
189.     pla 
190.     cmp cactusYCollisionIndex
191.     bne :+
192.     lda gameState
193.     ora #isGameOver
194.     sta gameState
195. :
196.     inx 
197.     inc playerXCollisionIndex
198.     cpx #$18
199.     bne checkCollisionX
200.     iny 
201.     inc playerYCollisionIndex
202.     cpy #$18
203.     bne checkCollisionY
204. endCheckCollision:
205.     rts
206. 
207. 
208. jump:
209.     lda playerState
210.     ora #isJumping
211.     sta playerState
212.     lda #$0B
213.     sta playerJumpSpeed
214.     rts
215. 
216. adjustLegPosition:
217.     lda #$08
218.     clc 
219.     adc #$0C
220.     clc 
221.     adc #$0D
222.     rts
223. 
224. 
225. 
226. update:
227.     lda #$01
228.     sta $4016
229.     lda #$00
230.     sta $4016
231.     lda $4016
232.     and #%00000001 
233.     cmp #%00000001
234.     bne A_not_pressed
235.     lda playerState
236.     and #isJumping
237.     cmp #$00
238.     bne A_not_pressed
239.     lda playerState
240.     and #isFalling
241.     cmp #$00
242.     bne A_not_pressed
243.     jsr jump
244. A_not_pressed:
245.     lda $4016
246.     and #%00000001
247.     cmp #%00000001 
248.     bne B_not_pressed
249. B_not_pressed:
250.     lda $4016
251.     and #%00000001
252.     cmp #%00000001
253.     bne Select_not_pressed
254. Select_not_pressed:
255.     lda $4016
256.     and #%00000001
257.     cmp #%00000001
258.     bne Start_not_pressed
259. Start_not_pressed:
260.     lda $4016
261.     and #%00000001
262.     cmp #%00000001
263.     bne Up_not_pressed
264.     lda playerState
265.     and #isJumping
266.     cmp #$00
267.     bne Up_not_pressed
268.     lda playerState
269.     and #isFalling
270.     cmp #$00
271.     bne Up_not_pressed
272.     jsr jump
273. Up_not_pressed:
274.     lda $4016
275.     and #%00000001
276.     cmp #%00000001
277.     bne Down_not_pressed
278. Down_not_pressed:
279.     lda $4016
280.     and #%00000001
281.     cmp #%00000001
282.     bne Left_not_pressed
283. Left_not_pressed:
284.     lda $4016
285.     and #%00000001
286.     cmp #%00000001
287.     bne Right_not_pressed
288. Right_not_pressed:
289. end_input:
290.     lda cactus1XPos
291.     sec 
292.     sbc cactusMoveSpeed
293.     sta cactus1XPos
294.     lda cactus2XPos 
295.     sec 
296.     sbc cactusMoveSpeed
297.     sta cactus2XPos
298.     inc walkingAnimationDelay
299.     lda walkingAnimationDelay
300.     cmp #$06
301.     bne :+
302.     lda #$00
303.     sta walkingAnimationDelay
304. :
305.     lda playerState
306.     and #isJumping
307.     cmp #$00
308.     bne setWalkingStateToZero
309.     lda playerState
310.     and #isFalling
311.     cmp #$00
312.     bne setWalkingStateToZero
313.     lda walkingAnimationDelay
314.     cmp #$05
315.     bne endWalkingAnimState     
316.     lda walkingAnimationState
317.     cmp #$01
318.     bne :+
319.     lda #$02
320.     sta walkingAnimationState
321.     jmp endWalkingAnimState
322. :   
323.     lda #$01
324.     sta walkingAnimationState
325.     jmp endWalkingAnimState
326. setWalkingStateToZero:
327.     lda #$00
328.     sta walkingAnimationState
329. endWalkingAnimState:
330. 
331. checkForJump:
332.     lda playerState
333.     and #isJumping
334.     cmp #$00
335.     beq :+
336.     lda playerYPos
337.     sec 
338.     sbc playerJumpSpeed
339.     sta playerYPos
340.     dec playerJumpSpeed
341.     lda playerJumpSpeed
342.     cmp #$00
343.     bne :+
344.     lda playerState
345.     eor #isJumping
346.     ora #isFalling
347.     sta playerState
348.     lda #$00
349.     sta playerFallSpeed
350. :
351. checkForFall:
352.     lda playerState
353.     and #isFalling
354.     cmp #$00
355.     beq :+
356.     lda playerYPos
357.     clc 
358.     adc playerFallSpeed
359.     sta playerYPos
360.     inc playerFallSpeed
361.     ldx playerXPos
362.     ldy playerYPos
363.     jsr CheckBackgroundCollision
364.     beq :+
365.     lda playerState
366.     eor #isFalling
367.     sta playerState
368. :
369.     lda cactus1XPos
370.     clc 
371.     adc #$08
372.     sta cactusTmpX
373.     lda cactus1YPos
374.     clc 
375.     adc #$08
376.     sta cactusTmpY
377.     jsr checkCactusCollision
378.     lda cactus2XPos
379.     sec 
380.     sbc #$08
381.     sta cactusTmpX
382.     lda cactus2YPos
383.     clc 
384.     adc #$08
385.     sta cactusTmpY
386.     jsr checkCactusCollision
387.     rts
388.     
389. draw:
390.     lda #$08
391.     clc 
392.     adc playerYPos
393.     sta $200
394.     lda #$00
395.     sta $201
396.     sta $202
397.     lda #$08
398.     clc 
399.     adc playerXPos
400.     sta $203
401.     lda #$08
402.     clc 
403.     adc playerYPos
404.     sta $204
405.     lda #$01
406.     sta $205
407.     lda #$00
408.     sta $206
409.     lda #$10
410.     clc 
411.     adc playerXPos
412.     sta $207
413.     lda #$08
414.     clc 
415.     adc playerYPos
416.     sta $208
417.     lda #$02
418.     sta $209
419.     lda #$00
420.     sta $20A
421.     lda #$18
422.     clc 
423.     adc playerXPos
424.     sta $20B
425.     lda #$08
426.     clc 
427.     adc playerYPos
428.     sta $20C
429.     lda #$03
430.     sta $20D
431.     lda #$00
432.     sta $20E
433.     lda #$20
434.     clc 
435.     adc playerXPos
436.     sta $20F
437.     lda #$10
438.     clc 
439.     adc playerYPos
440.     sta $210
441.     lda #$04
442.     clc 
443.     adc #$0C
444.     sta $211
445.     lda #$00
446.     sta $212
447.     lda #$08
448.     clc 
449.     adc playerXPos
450.     sta $213
451.     lda #$10
452.     clc 
453.     adc playerYPos
454.     sta $214
455.     lda #$05
456.     clc 
457.     adc #$0C
458.     sta $215
459.     lda #$00
460.     sta $216
461.     lda #$10
462.     clc 
463.     adc playerXPos
464.     sta $217
465.     lda #$10
466.     clc 
467.     adc playerYPos
468.     sta $218
469.     lda #$06
470.     clc 
471.     adc #$0C
472.     sta $219
473.     lda #$00
474.     sta $21A
475.     lda #$18
476.     clc 
477.     adc playerXPos
478.     sta $21B
479.     lda #$18
480.     clc 
481.     adc playerYPos
482.     sta $21C
483.     lda #$07
484.     clc 
485.     adc #$0C
486.     clc 
487.     adc #$0D
488.     sta $21D
489.     lda #$00
490.     sta $21E
491.     lda #$08
492.     clc 
493.     adc playerXPos
494.     sta $21F
495.     lda #$18
496.     clc 
497.     adc playerYPos
498.     sta $220
499.     lda walkingAnimationState
500.     cmp #$01
501.     beq setWalkingToWalking1
502.     cmp #$02
503.     beq setWalkingToWalking2
504.     jsr adjustLegPosition
505.     jmp :+
506. setWalkingToWalking1:
507.     jsr adjustLegPosition
508.     clc 
509.     adc #$02
510.     jmp :+
511. setWalkingToWalking2:
512.     jsr adjustLegPosition
513.     clc 
514.     adc #$03
515. :
516.     sta $221
517.     lda #$00
518.     sta $222
519.     lda #$10
520.     clc 
521.     adc playerXPos
522.     sta $223
523.     lda #$18
524.     clc 
525.     adc playerYPos
526.     sta $224
527.     lda #$09
528.     clc 
529.     adc #$0C
530.     clc 
531.     adc #$0D
532.     sta $225
533.     lda #$00
534.     sta $226
535.     lda #$18
536.     clc 
537.     adc playerXPos
538.     sta $227
539.     lda #$08
540.     clc 
541.     adc cactus1YPos 
542.     sta $228
543.     lda #$04
544.     sta $229
545.     lda #$00
546.     sta $22A
547.     lda  #$08
548.     clc 
549.     adc cactus1XPos
550.     sta $22B
551.     lda #$08
552.     clc 
553.     adc cactus1YPos 
554.     sta $22C
555.     lda #$05
556.     sta $22D
557.     lda #$00
558.     sta $22E
559.     lda #$10
560.     clc 
561.     adc cactus1XPos
562.     sta $22F
563.     lda #$10
564.     clc 
565.     adc cactus1YPos 
566.     sta $230
567.     lda #$05
568.     clc 
569.     adc #$0F
570.     sta $231
571.     lda #$00
572.     sta $232
573.     lda  #$08
574.     clc 
575.     adc cactus1XPos
576.     sta $233
577.     lda #$10
578.     clc 
579.     adc cactus1YPos 
580.     sta $234
581.     lda #$05
582.     clc 
583.     adc #$10
584.     sta $235
585.     lda #$00
586.     sta $236
587.     lda #$10
588.     clc 
589.     adc cactus1XPos
590.     sta $237
591.     lda #$08
592.     clc 
593.     adc cactus2YPos 
594.     sta $238
595.     lda #$16
596.     sta $239
597.     lda #$00
598.     sta $23A
599.     lda #$08
600.     clc 
601.     adc cactus2XPos 
602.     sta $23B
603.     lda #$08
604.     clc 
605.     adc cactus2YPos
606.     sta $23C
607.     lda #$17
608.     sta $23D
609.     lda #$00
610.     sta $23E
611.     lda #$10
612.     clc 
613.     adc cactus2XPos
614.     sta $23F
615.     lda #$10
616.     clc
617.     adc cactus2YPos 
618.     sta $240
619.     lda #$26
620.     sta $241
621.     lda 00
622.     sta $242
623.     lda #$08
624.     clc 
625.     adc cactus2XPos 
626.     sta $243
627.     lda #$10
628.     clc 
629.     adc cactus2YPos 
630.     sta $244
631.     lda #$27
632.     sta $245
633.     lda #$00
634.     sta $246
635.     lda #$10
636.     clc 
637.     adc cactus2XPos 
638.     sta $247
639.     lda #$18
640.     clc 
641.     adc cactus2YPos 
642.     sta $248
643.     lda #$36
644.     sta $249
645.     lda #$00 
646.     sta $24A
647.     lda #$08
648.     clc 
649.     adc cactus2XPos
650.     sta $24B
651.     lda #$18
652.     clc 
653.     adc cactus2YPos 
654.     sta $24C
655.     lda #$37
656.     sta $24D
657.     lda #$00
658.     sta $24E
659.     lda #$10
660.     clc 
661.     adc cactus2XPos 
662.     sta $24F
663.     lda #$20
664.     clc 
665.     adc cactus2YPos 
666.     sta $250
667.     lda #$46
668.     sta $251
669.     lda #$00
670.     sta $252
671.     lda #$08
672.     clc 
673.     adc cactus2XPos
674.     sta $253
675.     lda #$20
676.     clc 
677.     adc cactus2YPos 
678.     sta $254
679.     lda #$47
680.     sta $255
681.     lda #$00
682.     sta $256
683.     lda #$10
684.     clc 
685.     adc cactus2XPos 
686.     sta $257
687.     rts 
688. 
689. NMI:
690.     lda #$00
691.     sta $2003
692.     lda #$02
693.     sta $4014
694.     lda gameState
695.     and #isGameOver
696.     cmp #$00
697.     bne :+
698.     jsr draw 
699.     jsr update
700.  :
701.     rti 
702.     
703. PaletteData:
704. .byte $30,$2D,$2D,$2D,$2D,$2D,$2D,$2D,$2D,$2D,$2D,$2D,$2D,$2D,$2D,$2D
705. .byte $30,$2D,$2D,$2D,$2D,$2D,$2D,$2D,$2D,$2D,$2D,$2D,$2D,$2D,$2D,$2D 
706. 
707. CollisionMap:
708.     .byte %00000000, %00000000, %00000000, %00000000
709.     .byte %00000000, %00000000, %00000000, %00000000
710.     .byte %00000000, %00000000, %00000000, %00000000
711.     .byte %00000000, %00000000, %00000000, %00000000
712.     .byte %00000000, %00000000, %00000000, %00000000
713.     .byte %00000000, %00000000, %00000000, %00000000
714.     .byte %00000000, %00000000, %00000000, %00000000
715.     .byte %00000000, %00000000, %00000000, %00000000
716.     .byte %00000000, %00000000, %00000000, %00000000
717.     .byte %00000000, %00000000, %00000000, %00000000
718.     .byte %00000000, %00000000, %00000000, %00000000
719.     .byte %00000000, %00000000, %00000000, %00000000
720.     .byte %00000000, %00000000, %00000000, %00000000
721.     .byte %00000000, %00000000, %00000000, %00000000
722.     .byte %00000000, %00000000, %00000000, %00000000
723.     .byte %00000000, %00000000, %00000000, %00000000
724.     .byte %00000000, %00000000, %00000000, %00000000
725.     .byte %00000000, %00000000, %00000000, %00000000
726.     .byte %00000000, %00000000, %00000000, %00000000
727.     .byte %11111111, %00000000, %00000000, %00000000
728.     .byte %11111111, %00000000, %00000000, %00000000
729.     .byte %00000000, %00000000, %00000000, %00000000
730.     .byte %00000000, %00000000, %00000000, %00000000
731.     .byte %00000000, %00000000, %00000000, %00000000
732.     .byte %00000000, %00000000, %00000000, %00000000
733.     .byte %00000000, %00000000, %00000000, %00000000
734.     .byte %00000000, %00000000, %00000000, %00000000
735.     .byte %00000000, %00000000, %00000000, %00000000
736.     .byte %00000000, %00000000, %00000000, %00000000
737.     .byte %00000000, %00000000, %00000000, %00000000
738.     
739. BitMask:
740.     .byte %10000000
741.     .byte %01000000
742.     .byte %00100000
743.     .byte %00010000
744.     .byte %00001000
745.     .byte %00000100
746.     .byte %00000010
747.     .byte %00000001
748.     
749. .segment "VECTORS"
750.     .word NMI
751.     .word Reset
752. .segment "CHARS"
753.     .incbin "chrrom.chr"
```

(this has nothing to do with checkBackgroundCollision and CollisionMap afaik)

The problem seems to occur at line 386 where it jumps to the checkCactusCollision subroutine (line 161) for the second time however, the previous time it jumped it didn't do anything. I've tried a lot of things including making the code closer to the subroutine, removing the push and pull commands in checkCactusCollision and replacing them with temporary memory addresses for storing the A register in and even just removing the subroutine jump and repeating the code in checkCactusCollision twice, however I still can't figure it out.

Help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Most people probably aren't going to go through hundreds of lines of assembly. Also, those like numbers make it impractical for people to try to run it themselves.

Comment: Nothing obviously wrong. No recursion and if the previous call on line 377 ran without issue then line 386 should too. Make sure that is actually where the problem is. You could replace the `jsr` + `rts` with just a `jmp` that should not use the stack. Still, that should work as is.

Comment: @Jester that fixed the problem, thanks

Answer (score -2):

The problem has been solved. Probably had something to do with the distance between the jsr and the subroutine.

Comment: What the 6502 puts on the stack following a `JSR` is unrelated to the distance of the jump — it's the return address, which is related to the address being jumped from, not to, and it has no way of knowing then where the relevant `RTS` will be. So it's always the full address.

Comment: ```JSR``` can go anywhere, it's not a distance issue. You probably made a typo when you programmed it and forgot to properly ensure the stack was "balanced" upon returning. It's a very common mistake, so not a big deal. I like to indent the code in my ```pha``` and ```pla``` statements, kind of like what curly brace language programmers do. It helps  make things easier on the eyes.